# Perl module error regarding "undefined subroutine"

Tags: perl, module, cygwin

I am trying to use a module called [Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Counting;

my $f = factorial(3);
print "$f\n";
```

When I run it however,  I get the following error

```
$ perl UsingModules.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::factorial called at UsingModules.pl line 8.
```

It seems like the function `factorial` is not being exported, but why?

When I used the following

```
my $f = Math::Counting::factorial(3);
```

instead of what was above, it works perfectly fine, but I am curious why the function cannot be exported.

I am using `perl` v5.10.1 on Cygwin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in the module. [Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting) `ISA` [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Exporter), but `Math::Counting` does not load `Exporter`.

Workaround: You can [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) or [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) `Exporter` manually.

Better: File a bug with the module author, provide a test case.

#### Comment:

*Oh, very interesting.  The module author does test his functions, but `Test::More` pulls in `Exporter`, meaning that this omission from the module source was not noticed.*

#### Update:

[Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting) 0.0904 has been released, addressing this issue.

Comment: @Sinan, thank you for the formatting and HREFs.  I've filed a bug under Test::Simple/Test::More.  It seems to me that suite should not pull in certain core modules, for precisely this reason.

Comment: UPDATE:  Math::Counting author is releasing a fix.

Answer (score 7):

[Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting) looks a little silly (I mean *student* versus *engineering* modes?) The *real* factorial function provided by the module, `bfact` is a thin wrapper around `Math::BigInt::bfac`. So, just use [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aBigInt).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Math::BigInt();

print Math::BigInt->bfac('300'), "\n";
```

Output:

```
30605751221644063603537046129726862938858880417357699941677674125947653317671686
74655152914224775733499391478887017263688642639077590031542268429279069745598412
25476930271954604008012215776252176854255965356903506788725264321896264299365204
57644883038890975394348962543605322598077652127082243763944912012867867536830571
22936819436499564604981664502277165001851765464693401122260347297240663332585835
06870150169794168850353752137554910289126407157154830282284937952636580145235233
15693648223343679925459409527682060806223281238738388081704960000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

*No*, [I did not verify the result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300!).

As others have noted, `Math::Counting` has:

```
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(
    factorial permutation combination
    bfact     bperm       bcomb
);
```

but there is no `require` [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

In fact, there is no need for this module to *inherit* from Exporter. A simple:

```
use Exporter 'import';
```

would have been enough. Also, there really is no need to pollute the namespace of a user of this module by default, so it should have:

```
our @EXPORT = ();
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
    factorial permutation combination
    bfact     bperm       bcomb
);
```

Otherwise, what's the point of defining `%EXPORT_TAGS`?

Comment: +1 for `use Exporter 'import'` vs. `use base qw(Exporter)` or equivalent techniques.  Another +1 (well, I hit the vote button repeatedly) for recommending no EXPORT by default.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting) is missing `require Exporter;` so none of it's functions are being exported to your namespace.

Answer (score 2):

After being alerted by a nice person who filed a bug report with CPAN regarding my forgotten require statement, I fixed up the module export, including the comment about "polluting the namespace."

Also, I added a note that it is a "thin wrapper" for `Math::BigInt->bfac()` for real world applications, in the docs.  When I made it, I could not find simple computations for permutation or combination.  Now there are a plethora...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Math::Counting module did not export the factorial method when you called it using `use Math::Counting`.

The CPAN page does the following

```
use Math::Counting ':student';
```

and afterwards the factorial method is exported into your namespace, and you can use it without prepending the entire package name.

Comment: Looking at http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GENE/Math-Counting-0.0902/lib/Math/Counting.pm, doesn't it export `factorial` by default?

Comment: It indeed did not export, and pilcrow found why: the module ISA exporter but does not load Exporter. Bang.

Comment: Strictly speaking, @nickisfat was the first one to post by seconds. Equal credit goes to both him/her and `@pilcrow`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for Math::Counting and see what version it is. You can find where the source is located by doing this:

```
prompt> perldoc -l Math::Counting
```

You can also find the version of a module about 90% of the time by looking at the module's `$VERSION` variable:

```
use Math::Dumper;
print "The version of Math::Dumper is $Math::Dumper::VERSION\n";
```

I just downloaded version 0.0902, and the following program works just fine:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Math::Counting;

say $Math::Counting::VERSION;
say factorial(6);
```

I notice in this version, he has:

```
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(
    factorial permutation combination
    bfact     bperm       bcomb
);
```

So, it looks like the author is automatically exporting all of their subroutines in this particular version. The author also has two groups of export tags defined `:student`, and `big`.

It could be in earlier versions, he didn't have `@EXPORT` defined, but used `@EXPORT_OK` (which is preferable), and you had to do this:

```
use Match::Counting qw(:student);
```

or

```
use Math::Counting qw(factorial);
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of `sitecustomize.pl`?  The program you provide fails for me with the OP's given error, and we know that 0.0902 doesn't load Exporter.pm, and so cannot export a `factorial()` sub.  How is that program working for you?

Comment: @pilcrow I don't believe so. I never created one. I have a Mac running Lion, and Iran my script on it. I checked the `/System/Library/Perl`, `/Library/Perl`, and `$HOME/Library` for any file that starts with `sitecustomizer`. In fact, I did a search on my whole system starting from root.

Comment: hmm. It's "sitecustomize" (no 'r').  Does the OP's original example fail for you under 0.0902?  Does keys(%INC) contain Exporter?

Comment: I didn't have my notebook, so I thought I'd try it on my wife's iMac. Whoops! `make` not installed. Install Xcode, then install the command line tools, now upgrade `CPAN`, and finally install `Math::Counting`. Whoops, it's at version `0.0904` and it has `use parent qw(Exporter)` in it. Interesting, everything is now `@EXPORT_OK`, so if you don't specify `use Math::Counting qw(factorial);`, it won't be exported.